# How can I split a file based on multiple column values

Tags: unix, awk, split, multiple-columns, aix

I need to take this test_file & split it to have a separate file for each unique combination of col5 and col6. 
Another caveaut is this file need to split after 150,000 records. Also the naming convetion needs to be pulled from the file as well:
"$5"_"$6"_P"sysdate"_IU"$4"*60""*[File #]".zip

test_file.csv

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ..... col32
1234, 6789, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1235, 1233, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1236, 4423, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 5678 ..... col32
1237, 3323, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1238, 0808, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1239, 2222, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 1234 ..... col32
1231, 4535, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 1234 ..... col32
1232, 8080, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 5678 ..... col32
1233, 7878, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 5678 ..... col32
```

Results should look like:

```
1000_1234_P20170203_IU20170131_60_1.ZIP
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ..... col32
1234, 6789, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1235, 1233, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1237, 3323, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32
1238, 0808, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 1234 ..... col32

1000_5678_P20170203_IU20170131_60_1.ZIP
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ..... col32
1236, 4423, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 1000, 5678 ..... col32

2000_1234_P20170203_IU20170131_60_1.ZIP
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ..... col32
1239, 2222, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 1234 ..... col32
1231, 4535, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 1234 ..... col32

2000_5678_P20170203_IU20170131_60_1.ZIP
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 ..... col32
1232, 8080, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 5678 ..... col32
1233, 7878, 1, 01/31/2017 00:00:00, 2000, 5678 ..... col32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

```
awk -F', *' -v sysdate="$(date +'%Y%m%d')" '
NR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
(cnt[$5,$6]++ % 150000) == 0 { sfx[$5,$6]++ }
{
    split($4,d,/[\/ ]/)
    out = $5 "_" $6 "_P" sysdate "_IU" d[3] d[1] d[2] "_60_" sfx[$5,$6] ".zip"
    if (!seen[out]++) {
        print hdr > out
    }
    print > out
}
' file
```

and massage to suit. If you don't use GNU awk you might have to `close()` the files as you go to avoid a "too many files open" error.

Comment: Thank you Ed. It seems to have worked except for column 4 but this is due to the date format. It puts a space in the name so I need to reformat this in the file so it should work after. Also the first row is a header so I need to skip splitting it but make sure to add it to the files.

Comment: I didn't attempt to open the files until now. Is the ZIP archiving working as it should? Each file needs to be a compressed ZIP for FTPing to a portal page. The input file is .csv then the files are being split into these ZIP files. ANy thoughts?

Comment: What zip archiving? The script splits a file as you asked for and generates the output you asked for given the input you provided. If you need to compress the output files or do anything else with them and don't know how to do that then ask a followup question about "zip" or whatever tool you want to use to do that (that question would have nothing to do with awk).